# Query Cases based on Last Modified DateTime and Last Modified By User

Tags: soql, case, developer-console

So here's the scenario. A user (lets call him John Doe) un-deleted the Cases records from the Recycle Bin and now they are back in the system along with current Case records. I need to delete them back.

Now those cases have last modified datetime as the time when they were un-deleted, so now I have my first filter criteria, second being where the last modified by user was John Doe.

I can run a report and get those Case Ids. However I need to run a query on the dev console to check some other stuff as well.

The suspected last modified date time we have for those cases is 06/29/2017 4:15 PM - 06/29/2017 5:00 PM

So in my dev console I want to do a query that looks like:

```
select Id, Subject from Case where LastModifiedDate >= 2017-06-29T16:15 and LastModifiedDate <= 2017-06-29T17:00 and LastModifiedBy = 'User Id for John Doe'
```

However, the LastModifiedDate and LastModifiedBy fields are not recognized and it is giving me error saying, "no such field on Case"

How do I make this query work? Do I need to query CaseHistory instead of Case? And what field name do I use for last modifed datetime and last modifed by user?

Answer (score 2):

Two things that are incorrect in your query:

- As glls mentioned, the date format must include the second and timezone parts
- You cannot directly use `LastModifiedBy`, you should use `LastModifiedBy.Name` to filter on the name of the user or `LastModifiedById` (convenience field available on all SObjects, the same as `LastModifiedBy.Id`)

The following query parses for me:

```
select Id, Subject from Case where LastModifiedDate >= 2017-06-29T16:15:00Z and LastModifiedDate <= 2017-06-29T17:00:00Z and LastModifiedBy.Name = 'User Id for John Doe'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your date formatting is incorrect, so your current query should be returning an unkown error while parsing the query.

your date formatting should be as follows:

```
2017-06-29T17:00:00Z
```

And try adding parenthesis for your expression after WHERE